# What's the approach to modify an Animate CC app and redistribute it

Tags: flash, animate-cc, fla

I have the source files of a flash application we outsourced years ago. I need to modify (add a logo) the app. Instead of outsourcing that again, we want to do it ourselves (we own the app).

The folder contains these files :

- Main folder

  - com/

    - greensock/
    - [...]
  - appName.app/

    - [...]
  - src/

    - [...]
  - data.xml
  - appName.exe
  - appName.fla
  - appName.swf
  - [...]

From what I understand from reading online, the .fla is the modifiable file and the .swf is the published version (unmodifiable).

So my question is, to add a logo to the app background design, what would be the approach to take ? Would modify the `appName.fla`, republish the `appName.swf` and then find how to generate the executable from that be the way to go ?

Comment: It is not clear what part of listed files you distribute. Could be EXE projector, or something Desktop AIR, but there's no telling.

Comment: We currently distribute the whole folder. It is only used by our employees. To use it they simply execute the appName.exe executable file. @Organis

Comment: Then it is most probably Windows Projector. You can modify FLA then publish EXE Projector (you can find it among other publish options).

Comment: I see. That way only the new executable file will need to replace the old one and nothing more (the .fla file would be modified to obviously). Am I correct to assume it will be that the only steps ?

Comment: Probably. There are too many uncertain points, but probably. Try it, it might just work.